# Is there a way to limit the update privilege in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I notice that sometimes users by mistake make an update like `update * from users`, without a where statement, this can cause loss of information, if i don't want to block the update privilege. How can i block this class of update?,

How do you overcome this situation?

Comment: I don't let users access the database directly. If they need something from it or need to do something to it, software is created/changed to allow them to do it properly with little to no chance of getting it wrong.

Comment: I like the idea of create software thath makes what users need to do without touching the database also if the users dont access the real database they can use a test database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the MAX_UPDATES or MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR privilege so even if a user makes an update whitout a where statement the number of records affected wont be all